# How grab names from tab with jQuery & send name data from host sheet to Name's sheet?-App Scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, autocomplete, send

I've finally obtain a shorter autocomplete function with jQuery. Now, I need to 1. obtain names from sheet tab "Name" for autocomplete function & 2. Once the Name is selected, send data to the Name's sheet from host sheet. The html/css is done for the page.

I've googled for days & I haven't found anyone who has done it before. I'm a newbie with jQuery/Javascript so please keep that in mind while providing your suggestions.

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Name 1",
      "Name 2",
      "Name 3"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Edit: Once the name is selected, send corresponding data to Name's sheet.
example: Date, Client, Time, Name 1. If Name 1 is selected, send date, client, & time to Name 1's sheet from host sheet. If name 2 is selected, send its data to Name 2. So on. I need it for about 25 different names.
thanks.

Comment: [Client To Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Hi ! Could you please clarify better your question with an example sheet (with no sensitive data)? What do you mean by ```grab names from tab```? Do you mean the sheet names?Let me know if I understood you well, you basically have a cell to select from different sheet names, once you select one you want to send the information of other cells ```Client``` and ```Time``` to the selected sheet, am I right?

Comment: I want to get the list of names from tab called "Name" when I submit info on the source sheet. I have a SpreadsheetApp.getUi running on the main document. This is just an example without it. I've included notes on the Spreadsheet Example link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dGtdvwud_gylJ_ZKS7GdmYFJislI-ZZUmq6wzH-jG6c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi ! From your explanation a possible solution is the following: create a data validation (*in your sheet go to Data->Data validation*) for your ```Source!B:B``` with the criteria of  *List from a range* with the range of ```Names!A2:Amax``` with *show dropdown list in cell* **unchecked** and on *invalid data* **reject input**. This can easily be achieved in the spreadsheet UI and therefore, also programmatically, so please **let me know if this is what you want so that I can formalise this comment into a solution with the right piece of code to achieve this**.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To suggest auto complete names from a list in your name sheet in a column of the source sheet you need to create a [data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).This can be achieved both through the UI and through Apps Script.

The focus point here is that when you create this data validation you don't want the dropdown list enabled (as your functionallity is just to auto complete names) and you don't want a UI alert every time you enter a name that is not in your name list.

### 1. Using Apps Scipts

The following piece of code will create your desired data validation. It has comments that explains how it works. To learn more about how to set up a data validation in your spreadsheet, check out the documentation for [Data Validation Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) and the methods used in this implementation: [newDataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newdatavalidation), [requireValueInRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange,-showdropdown) and [setAllowInvalid](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#setallowinvalidallowinvaliddata).

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get source range where we want the auto complete text
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Source').getRange('B:B');
  
  // Get the range of the list of names we want to auto complete
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Name').getRange('A1:A5');
  
  // Create a data validation rule with the dropdown list disables (this will allow to only show the name suggestions
  // and set allow invalid false to avoid the ui to pop a message every time you enter a value not in the list
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range, false).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  
  // Set the data validation to our range where we want the auto complete function
  myRange.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

### 2. Using the UI

Create a data validation (in your sheet go to **Data->Data validation**) for your `Source!B:B` with the criteria of *List from a range* with the range of `Names!A2:Amax` with *show dropdown list in cell* **unchecked** and on *invalid data* **reject input**.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)